# antd dropdown is not closing on mouse leave

Tags: reactjs, antd

Using antd for adding an dropdown menu.Its not closing on mouse leave and click of an item inside dropdown.it remains open in the same place when page is scrolled.

```
<Dropdown  className="buy-dropdown" overlay={menu} placement="topLeft" trigger={["click"]   >       
   <Button className="cxe-buy-game-btn" >
      <img src="/static/images/cart-buy.svg" /> Buy
   </Button>
</Dropdown>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have mentioned `click` as trigger. remove this prop so default will be `hover` or add `hover`

```
<Dropdown  className="buy-dropdown" overlay={menu} placement="topLeft" trigger={["hover"]   >       
   <Button className="cxe-buy-game-btn" >
      <img src="/static/images/cart-buy.svg" /> Buy
   </Button>
</Dropdown>
```

Comment: In Some Cases I need trigger on Click

Comment: you can add multiple , it's an array